# Vector subespaces with the same dimension

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $K$ be a field and let $V$ be a vector space on $K$. Let $S , T$ two vector subespaces in $V$, with $S \neq T$, such that $\dim S = \dim T$. Prove that
$$
S \setminus T \neq \emptyset \neq T \setminus S\mbox{.}
$$

Comment: @OP : you did ask a question 3 hours ago and I did answer to you. You didn't say anything and instead asked another question, related to the same topic. I think this is not very respectful.

Comment: Thank you by your last answer and sorry if you are upset but I deleted these question because I think that it wasn't written well. Anyway this question has nothing to do with the other question.

Comment: I'm not upset, I'm just surprised. This is not a very honest attitude to my humble opinion.

Comment: I think I've given you some reasons. Sorry if you are surprised and thank you again by your answer in the question that I deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Prove (this may be completely trivial, depending on what you know...) simply that

$$\;S\not\subset T\;\;\;\text{and also}\;\;\;T\not\subset S\;$$

Comment: Can you help me to prove that $S \not \subset T$ for example?

Comment: @jose Suppose $\;S\le T\;$, but they have the same dimension $\;\implies S=T\;$, contradiction...!

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $S \subseteq T$ and $\dim S = \dim T$ imply $S=T$.